# PHP MySQL page, additional HTML to show count of results

Tags: php, html, mysql

Ok so I have this PHP page.

Anyone able to help me add in a count of rows?

```
<h2>All Open Incidents</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-head-bordered-bottom table-condensed">
  <thead>
   <tr>
  <th class=span1>Ticket ID</th>
  <th class=span2>Title</th>
  <th class=span2>Submitter</th>
  <th class=span2>Owner</th>
  <th class=span2>Status</th>
  <th class=span1>Created</th>
  <th class=span1>Modified</th>
  <th class=span1>SLA</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php

$query1 = "
SELECT HD_TICKET.ID as ID, 
HD_TICKET.TITLE as Title, 
HD_STATUS.NAME AS Status, 
HD_PRIORITY.NAME AS Priority, 
HD_TICKET.CREATED as Created, 
HD_TICKET.MODIFIED as Modified, 
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE10 as SLA,
S.FULL_NAME  as Submitter, 
O.FULL_NAME  as Owner, 
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 as Type  
FROM HD_TICKET  
JOIN HD_STATUS ON (HD_STATUS.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID) 
JOIN HD_PRIORITY ON (HD_PRIORITY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER S ON (S.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER O ON (O.ID = HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID) 
WHERE (HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID = $mainQueueID) AND 
(HD_STATUS.NAME like '%Open%')  
ORDER BY ID DESC

";


$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$num = mysql_num_rows($result1);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $num)

{
$ID = mysql_result($result1,$i,"ID");
$Title = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Title");
$Status = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Status");        
$Type = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Type");
$Created = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Created");
$Modified = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Modified");
$Priority = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Priority");
$Owner = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Owner"); 
$Submitter = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Submitter");
$SLA= mysql_result($result1,$i,"SLA");

$ID = stripslashes($ID);
$Title = stripslashes($Title);
$Status = stripslashes($Status);
$Type = stripslashes($Type);
$Created = stripslashes($Created);  
$Modified = stripslashes($Modified);
$Priority = stripslashes($Priority);
$Owner = stripslashes($Owner);
$Submitter = stripslashes($Submitter);
$SLA = stripslashes($SLA);


$StatusSpan="";
if ($Status=="Stalled")
{
    $StatusSpan="<span class='label label-warning'>$Status</span>";
}

$PriortySpan="";
if ($Priority=="High")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label label-important'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign icon-white'></i>High</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Low")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Low</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Medium")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Medium</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Critical")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign icon-white'></i>Critical</span>";
}


echo "<tr><td><a href='http://$KaceBoxDNS/adminui/ticket.php?ID=$ID' target='_blank'>$ID</a>     $StatusSpan $PriortySpan</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Title</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Submitter</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Owner</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Status</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Created</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Modified</td> \n";
echo "<td>$SLA</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";


$i++;
}

echo "</tbody></table> \n";
?>
```

So basically, I want to count the number of results (8 for instance) and display

8 Results Found

At the moment I can get it to count, but it loops and puts "8 results found" 8 times, any help would be greatly apprecaited.

:)

Comment: Why not just move your count outside of the loop and it wont say it 8 times. I also dont see this part of the code in your post.

Comment: Didn't I already answer this here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25734416/1491895

Comment: @Barmar That response seems to apply to a lot of SO questions, though...

Comment: @ialarmedalien Yeah, but most of the time it's not just an hour earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the number of results is in `$num`, you just need to add the line outside the `while ($i < $num)` loop, e.g. after the table close tag:

```
echo "</tbody></table>\n";
echo "<p>$num results found! Woohoo!</p>";
```